# How to display android POST string on PHP server?

Tags: java, php, android, json, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send json string from my android app to my php server. Below is the complete code from my mobiledb_control.php and httpconnect.java

The Log.v("HTTPSENDER","WORKED"); runs, and I get no errors.
However my error_log("in"); does not run.

How do I display the JSON sent via android into my error_log() ?

**HttpConnect.java:**

```
public class HttpConnect {
    public HttpConnect(){

    }
    public void sendData(String jsonObject){
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.alextanti.net/PHPDashboard/Backend/mobiledb_control.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            output.write("json="+jsonObject);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            Log.v("HTTPSENDER","WORKED");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**mobiledb_control.php:**

```
   <?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set("error_log", "../Logs/error.log");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(!empty($_POST['json'])){
  echo(var_dump($_POST['json']));
  error_log($_POST['json']);
}
$headers = apache_request_headers();

?>
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need to encode your string using UTF 8 in you Android App

Comment: `jsonObject` ?? What is that? We cannot even see the type. You can only write a String there. The string should be url encoded.

Comment: `if($_POST)` ??? What is that for kind of statement?

Comment: `if($_POST['json'])` ?? Do you mean: `if ( isset($_POST['json']))` ?

Comment: My mistake had not updated the code, still with the problem tho. I am not sure if it is PHP side or Java side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to have fixed it but I have no idea how

**PHP File:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set("error_log", "../Logs/location.log");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(!empty($_POST['json'])){
  echo(var_dump($_POST['json']));
  error_log($_POST['json']);
}
?>
```

**JAVA File:**

```
public class HttpConnect {
    public HttpConnect(){

    }
    public void sendData(String jsonObject){
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.alextanti.net/PHPDashboard/Backend/mobiledb_control.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            output.write("json="+jsonObject);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            Log.v("HTTPSENDER","WORKED");
            Log.v("HTTPSENDER",""+conn.getResponseCode());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in PHP code

and turn on error reporting like this

```
// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

and

```
print_r($_POST);
```

for more clarification what you are getting from post.

Comment: Could there be something wrong in the parameters from the java side ?

Comment: you can check your logs for the same. if any error occurs then it will be shown in logcat

Comment: Prints "Array ( )" only

Answer (score 0):

1. use encode and decode functions of php for making and parsing json.

   ```
    $request=json_decode($_POST['json']); // it gives the Array
     foreach($request as $values){
     echo($values['your_value1'])
      echo($values['your_value2'])
     }
   ```

please refer this url : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: In the updated code I used var_dump which should display the whole json string but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In designing server-client communication, it is imperative to make sure both client and server can communicate with each other. With that in mind, can you please provide the server response code by adding this in your code inside try block:

```
try {
 ...
 Log.d(TAG, "code: " + conn.getReturnCode());
 InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
 String serverReply = readIt(is, 500);
 Log.d(TAG, serverReply);
 ...
}

public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

> It will return 200 and 401 respectively. Returns -1 if no code can be
>   discerned from the response (i.e., the response is not valid HTTP).

Cheers!

Comment: It did indeed return 200

Comment: cool. i can see in your php code that you echo back POST data. going back to your java code, let's read back this reply from the server. Please see my edit.

Comment: It seemed to work now, I have no idea what  I did but you can see my working code I posted somewhere here. Maybe you can find out what I changed because I have no clue

Comment: Could be the conn.getResponseCode? You can check what other tasks it does from its source code in android's github.